# why is faillog, tallylog and lastlog so big?

Tags: linux, systemd, syslog

I got a notice from a backup system (rsnapshot) today that it's storage volume was full. A closer look reveals some older snapshots where `faillog`, `tallylog` and `lastlog` are bigger than the actual filesystem they are on (`/var` is a 6G partition).

```
-rw-r--r--  3 root       root             65G Feb 11 08:33 faillog
-rw-------  3 root       root            129G Feb 11 08:33 tallylog
-rw-rw-r--  2 root       utmp            585G Feb 11 08:57 lastlog
```

Redhat [says this is normal](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1808112). Any way to limit the size on these? Can they be safely rotated every few hours?

Comment: Use `du` or `ls -s` to determine actual file size.   The number shown by `ls -l` is not the file size, but the file length, which don't match for sparse files.

Comment: What? That makes absolutely no sense. `-l` is the short for `listing` format.

Comment: I always thought `ls -l` was "long format" not listing format, and the man page agrees.  You could use `ls -ls` and get both size and length at once.

Comment: `man lastlog` says ```The lastlog file is a database which contains info on the last login of each user. You should not rotate it. It is a sparse file, so its size on the disk is usually much smaller than the one shown by "ls -l" (which can indicate a really big file if you have in passwd users with a high UID). You can display its real size with "ls -s". ```

Answer (score 0):

> Redhat says this is normal. Any way to limit the size on these? Can they be safely rotated every few hours?

What RedHat says is that it's a [sparse file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file). That's a file where the length of the file is larger than the content of the file; it has *holes* what doesn't contain any data.

To back up sparse files, use a tool that recognizes sparse files and can handle them correctly.

You should *not* rotate the files; that won't solve your problem. Rather, you should configure [`rsnapshot` to use the `--sparse` flag](https://lists.samba.org/archive/rsync/2003-August/007000.html). Or use a better backup tool. Or not back up those files.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the `--sparse` flag. I'll give it a shot.